# Passing string to my C program inside a bash script

Tags: bash

I have a C program and I need to test program reads `stdin` when called like this

```
./program
```

Now I have to write a bash script that will send it an increassingly long string! For example first `a`, then `aa`, `aaa`, `aaaa` and so on. How can I do this?

I already found a nice way to construct a string (I iterate over `string_length`):

```
string=(head -c string_length < /dev/zero | tr '\0' '\141')
```

but how do I pass it to my program using `stdin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example might be a hint.

```c
//test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[100];
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("string: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
```

```sh
$ echo -n goodluck | ./test
string: goodluck
```